# Xcode image slicing - stretch the outsides of the image but preserve an area in the centre

Tags: ios, xcode, image, slice

I want to use image slicing in Xcode to produce a resizable image with a central area that is held static. It seems that this is impossible in Xcode as it only allows for one stretched area and one shrunk area in each direction. Is this correct?

[image: Resizable image]

Does anyone know of a nice workaround for this? I need to use the image for a button so I can't do an arrangement of UIImageViews on top of each other unless I pass touches through and that gets a bit messy.

Many thanks.

Comment: That is not possible using xcode slicing

Comment: You can use `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight` function of `UIImage` which allows you to create stretchable image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` is deprecated with iOS 5.0, You can use `resizableImageWithCapInsets`. Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:), It states,

> You use this method to add cap insets to an image or to change the existing cap insets of an image. In both cases, you get back a new image and the original image remains untouched. For example, you can use this method to create a background image for a button with borders and corners: when the button is resized, the corners of the image remain unchanged, but the borders and center of the image expand to cover the new size.

Another method is also available, `resizableImage(withCapInsets:resizingMode:)` if you want to set `resizingMode`

you can do something like,

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];

UIImage *streachedImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];  //Edgeinsect that you want

// OR

UIImage *streachedImage2 = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

// OR

UIImage *streachedImage3 = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

Check the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:) for more details.

**Update :** (According to comment)

You need to just set `backgroundImage` and `image` both to your button. You can set `image inset` also to manage your `image`'s position.

Comment: This stretches the middle of the image. I need to keep the part of the image with the house the same size, and stretch the rest of the image around it.

Comment: Then you should use two image. one background image and one as foreground said it house image!!

Comment: I mentioned that in my question. I will use the image for a UIButton so it gets messy if I have to place the button and then an image over the top. Will need to pass touches to the button or use two buttons with the same action. Also need to handle resizing at runtime. Was hoping for a nicer solution!

Comment: You can set `backgroundImage` and `image` both to button!! and you can set image inset also to manage the position of `image` (forground)

Comment: have you tried ? tell me if it's work for you then i will add it to answer!

Comment: Good idea. That's the answer! So simple too.